# Using iptables to block all internet-originating traffic except for a specific port

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I have an Emby server running on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS and would like to configure iptables to block all incoming connections from the internet except for port 8920, but allow normal incoming connections (ssh, etc.) from nodes on the local network.  Is this possible?  (I am doing this because my Zyxel router, an EMG3425-Q10A, is not doing port forwarding correctly.  Still working to resolve that.)

Comment: No reason.  But I noticed that iptables was bundled too.  That is why I asked about it.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do what you want with iptables. Is everything coming in on one network interface card? Myself, I find iptables easier to work with than ufw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an iptables script. The LAN (Local Area Network) and interface definitions are for my test computer and would have to be changed for the users requirements:

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ cat ask1337350
#!/bin/sh
FWVER=0.01
#
# ask1337350 Smythies 2021.05.10 Ver:0.01
#       See here:
#       https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337350/using-iptables-to-block-all-internet-originating-traffic-except-for-a-specific-p
#       run as sudo on s19.
#
#       Note: These rules likely need to be merged with
#       any existing iptables rules set.

echo "Loading ask1337350 rule set version $FWVER..\n"

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

#Setting the EXTERNAL and INTERNAL interfaces and addresses for the network
#
# Set for Smythies s19 computer (for testing). Edit for ask1337350's computer.
# EXTIF="enp3s0" no,no,no use the bridge br0, or everything breaks, big time.
EXTIF="br0"
EXTIP="192.168.111.136"
NETWORK="192.168.111.0/24"
UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

# Clearing any previous configuration
# Be careful here. I can do this on s18, but do not know
# about vxsa4's computer.
#
echo "  Clearing any existing rules and setting default policies.."
$IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP
$IPTABLES -F INPUT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F OUTPUT
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F FORWARD
$IPTABLES -t nat -F

# Delete user defined chains
$IPTABLES -X
# Reset all IPTABLES counters
$IPTABLES -Z
# Smythies: While my references do not have it, I think this is needed.
$IPTABLES -t nat -Z

# loopback interfaces are valid.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo -s $UNIVERSE -d $UNIVERSE -j ACCEPT

# Allow any related traffic coming back to the server in.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -s $UNIVERSE -d $EXTIP -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow in any LAN traffic
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -s $NETWORK -i $EXTIF -j ACCEPT

# Also allow in port 8920 traffic from anywhere
# The question does not specify a protocol. Do both.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT --protocol udp --destination-port 8920 -i $EXTIF -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT --protocol tcp --destination-port 8920 -i $EXTIF -j ACCEPT

# Do not allow in anything else
# Could also just fall through to default policy here, but sometimes a logging rule is also desired.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -j DROP

# At this point carry on. This might need to be merged into whatever existing iptables rule set.
#
echo ask1337350 rule set version $FWVER done.
```

Giving this, after a short time:

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ sudo iptables -xvnL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       8      616 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
     133     7916 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.111.136      state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
      51     3355 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       192.168.111.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:8920
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8920
      19     5880 DROP       all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 90 packets, 12122 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: This is just what I am looking for.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @BobReed :If my answer solves or help with your issue, then consider accepting it and/or upvoting it. That way future readers/searchers gain input as to usefulness.